# How to label each bar on X axis using histogram in R in PowerBi

Tags: r, plot, powerbi

I'm using R and PowerBI. I use `hist()` function for histogram and it does the job. 
I'm not able to put labels for each bar on x axis. The closes parameter I found is called  `labels = TRUE`

[image]

I want each bar to have a value that is increment of 10,000 in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

assign the histogram to a variable and then obtain the values to plot and co-ordinates to plot at from that variable. Set `xaxt = "n"` to supress x-axis at first and then use `axis` to add the desired x-axis. Read more at `?par`

```
set.seed(42)
x = rnorm(250)
h = hist(x, xaxt = "n")
text(x = h$mids, y = h$counts, labels = h$counts, pos = 3)
axis(side = 1, at = h$mids, seq_along(h$mids)*10000, las = 2)
```